# Move multiple tables with prefix to archive database with prepared statement, why is this MySQL statement invalid?

Tags: mysql, syntax-error, prepared-statement, archive

I am attempting to move multiple tables from one database to another and archive them, but the below statement fails with a syntax error on the select with:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '@tbls ENGINE=archive RENAME @tbls.database_two' at line 1
```

The select statement is identical to the syntax suggested in the manual and it doesn't seem as if I'm running into a capitalization error either.

What am I missing?

```
SET GROUP_CONCAT_MAX_LEN=10000;
SET @tbls = (
    SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(TABLE_NAME)
    FROM information_schema.TABLES
    WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'database_one'
    AND TABLE_NAME LIKE 'prefix_%'
);
SET @rnStmt = CONCAT('ALTER TABLE @tbls ENGINE=archive RENAME @tbls.database_two');
-- SELECT @rnStmt;
PREPARE stmt FROM @rnStmt;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

MySQL 5.1
CentOS 6.5

edit: copied wrong error msg

UPDATE: Made some progress, the select works and the sytax check but I'm getting 'No Database Selected' on the prepare statement.

```
SET GROUP_CONCAT_MAX_LEN=10000;
SET @tbls = (
    SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(TABLE_NAME)
    FROM information_schema.TABLES
    WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'database_one'
    AND TABLE_NAME LIKE 'prefix_%'
);
SET @rnStmt = CONCAT('ALTER TABLE ', @tbls, ' ENGINE=archive RENAME database_two.', @tbls);
PREPARE stmt FROM @rnStmt;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

I've tried USE and a few other variations, but no luck.

Comment: Missing `)` after `SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(TABLE_NAME`

Comment: You need one of these ")" (the error message kind of told you that)

Comment: That was a posting error, I'm trying to construct the statement in Notepadd++ and copying it into the browser borked the formatting a bit. The same error occurs. Is it because I'm using the variable name twice? Unsure if that is allowed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For multiple tables you need to use RENAME TABLE statement, and also, you need to collect full current table names and full new table names, then construct the result query and execute it -

```
SELECT
  GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT('database_one.',TABLE_NAME)),
  GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT('database_two.',TABLE_NAME))
INTO
  @from, @to
FROM
  information_schema.TABLES
WHERE
  TABLE_SCHEMA = 'database_one' AND TABLE_NAME LIKE 'prefix_%';

SET @rnStmt = CONCAT('RENAME TABLE ', @from, ' TO ', @to);

PREPARE stmt FROM @rnStmt;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

Comment: This is excellent, thank you. I had gotten it to work a minute ago by removing the engine specification, but it had some other unintended consequences so I didn't post it as a solution.

Comment: One last question. If I were to attempt this on several (100+) tables and convert them to archives, would I need to use a stored procedure?

Comment: >convert them to archives - What do you mean?

Comment: The archive storage engine, these tables are being retired but the data is to be retained.

Comment: In this case you should generate multiple ALTER TABLE statements, for each table. You can do it in the same way.